# Drop multiple columns at the same time from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, alter-table

I am currently looking some way to delete multiple columns at the same time from a given table in sql server.

One way of doing that is to use ALTER statement as shown below:

```
Alter Table [USER_DB].[dbo].my_Table
DROP COLUMN "ID", 
            "Name", 
            "Relationship"  ;
```

I am using above statement in some stored procedure to drop the columns and it's working fine. However, it creates problem when I re-ran this statement and columns are already dropped.

I found some nice solution on SO which doesn't fails even when columns are dropped.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_Table'
          and column_name= 'ID'
          and Table_SChema='DBO')
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE my_Table
    DROP COLUMN 
     ID
  END
```

I tried above statement to drop multiple columns at the same time but it's not working.

I was looking something like this.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_Table'
          and column_name= 'ID'
          and column_name= 'Name'
          and column_name ='Relationship'
          and Table_SChema='DBO')
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE my_Table
    DROP COLUMN 
     ID
    ,Name
    ,Relationship
  END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently looking for a column_name that has different values, so you'll never pass the test. You have to search in different rows to make it work.

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_Table'
              and column_name= 'ID')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_Table'
              and column_name= 'Relationship')
      BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE my_Table
        DROP COLUMN 
         ID
        ,Name
        ,Relationship
      END
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I have tested it. though we need to add many select statements in case we are dropping some 10 or 20 columns. but I am happy and accepting it as an answer. Thank you.